# How to access the type of the outer class for a type?

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I have legacy code that I cannot change:

```cpp
namespace ns1 {

struct ObjectType {
    enum class Value { VALUE1, VALUE2 };
    static const char* toString(Value);
};

struct Object {
    ObjectType::Value getTypeValue();
};

}
```

There also is a function that uses that legacy code, it gets the `ns1::Object` as a parameter, and uses the `ns::ObjectType::toString` static method:

```cpp
void func(const ns1::Object &object) {
    auto str = ns1::ObjectType::toString(object.getTypeValue());
}

ns1::Object object;
func(object);
```

Now I'm getting another legacy code that looks identically, but it is defined in another namespace, e.g. `ns2`.

I'm trying to generalize the function `func` to accept any type of objects, but the template depends on the `ObjectType` which I'm trying to avoid:

```cpp
template<typename OBJECT_TYPE, typename OBJECT>
void func(const OBJECT &object) {
    auto str = OBJECT_TYPE::toString(object.getTypeValue());
}

ns1::Object object1;
func<ns1::ObjectType>(object1);
ns2::Object object2;
func<ns2::ObjectType>(object2);
```

My goal is to remove this dependency:

```cpp
template<typename OBJECT>
void func(const OBJECT &object) {
    //...
}

ns1::Object object1;
func(object1);
ns2::Object object2;
func(object2);
```

Is that possible? Having the type of the object I could create an alias for the `ObjectType::Value`, but that doesn't help to access the method `ObjectType::toString`:

```cpp
using ObjectTypeValue = typename std::decay<decltype(object.getValue())>::type;
```

Comment: You can create a traits type. `template<typename> struct object_traits; template<>struct object_traits<ns1::Object> { using parent = ns1::ObjectType; }; template<>struct object_traits<ns2::Object> { using parent = ns2::ObjectType; };` Now you can use `object_traits<OBJECT>::parent`.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without manually specifying it somewhere. Like a type-trait.

Comment: @RaymondChen, type traits is a valid solution, but my main concern is how to access the type from its nested or sibling types. Logically there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ doesn't provide a way to walk around the type hierarchy as far as I know.